# maven download stuck at invalid path

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When I run `mvn package` on a Linux server, the downloading will stuck at the following URL and waited until timeout.

```
Downloading: http://repo.spring.io/ext-release-local/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-bom/1.0.1/shrinkwrap-bom-1.0.1.pom
```

I've browsed several related questions but couldn't find a working solution. My main questions are,

1. How do I find out where this dependency is coming from? In my IntelliJ IDE I couldn't find this pom dependency, and it builds fine on my laptop. The problem only happens on this specific Linux server. I'm using Maven 3.2.5. Tried `mvn dependency:tree` won't work as it'll try this downloading first as well.
2. What's the best way for me to bypass this issue. I tried setting the following in my settings.xml following some answers here, but this doesn't work either.

   `<repository>
           <id>spring.repo</id>
           <url>http://repo.spring.io/ext-release-local</url>
           <releases>
               <enabled>false</enabled>
           </releases>
           <snapshots>
               <enabled>false</enabled>
           </snapshots>
       </repository>`

Comment: I think maven works with a local repo; it's possible that while that URL was active it got downloaded to your laptop, but it's not available anymore, so it's breaking on your server.

Comment: @IsaacKleinman The case I observed is a little tricky. The reason it worked fine on my laptop is that it still tries this invalid URL first, but quickly timed out and switched to a working URL and moved along. On this Linux server though, the timeout is much longer (like 10 minutes). So given enough time it'll still pass but very annoying. So if I know how to make it timeout quickly I can live with that.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution

step 0 
check if http://repo.spring.io/ext-release-local/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-bom/1.0.1/shrinkwrap-bom-1.0.1.pom file exists on server

you can download all the files under following folder using browser 
http://repo.spring.io/ext-release-local/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-bom/1.0.1/

step2.
move all the files downloaded manually to

"YOUR_REPO_ROOT"/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-bom/1.0.1/

step 3. try to run maven package

Comment: right, i thought about that if manually put the files in position in local repo it should be fine, but this is still a headache, so probably will be my last resort if nothing else available. But I'm still counting on something better as I feel this should be common to a lot of people as I use all regular Spring dependencies.